# Método find javascript

Tags: javascript, find

estoy haciendo un ejercicio y me encuentro con algo particular del find que no sabria entender como es que pasa eso. Tengo entendido que el find trae el primer elemento que coindice con la condición, en este caso agarro ese objeto dentro del array y lo guardo en una variable, después le modifico ese nombre pero al consologuear el array me modifica la propiedad del array y en ningún momento la estoy "pisando" por así decirlo. Mi pregunta es, porque me modifica el objeto del array si no estoy haciendo cambios en el, solo en el de la variable

```
let brands = [{ name: "Peugeot" }];

let otro = brands.find((brand) => brand.name == "Peugeot");

otro.name = "Ford";

console.log(brands);
```

Comment: La respuesta de Trauma es correcta. Y es de suma importancia conocer la diferencia entre 'por valor' y 'por referencia', sobre todo en javascript, ya que es la base de muchos Front-End Frameworks, donde mutar un objeto puede tener consecuencias inesperadas. Por cierto, ambos conceptos (valor y referencia) existen en muchos otros lenguajes de programación como Java y C#. DEBES conocer la teoría. Te ahorrarás muchos errores en el futuro.

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema es que, en JavaScript, los objetos se *usan* **por referencia**.

Eso quiere decir que el resultado de `find( )` es **una referencia** al objeto dentro de `brands`. No es una copia, es la misma instancia.

Usando el símil de direcciones de casas: imagina una casa a la que tienes acceso por 2 calles distintas. Cada calle sería una dirección ... pero la casa es **la misma**.

Pues algo similar. Tienes 2 referencias al objeto: `brands[0]` y `otro`. Y si crearas otra nueva variable

```
let OtroOtro = otro;
```

pues ahora tienes **3** referencias al mismo objeto. Por lo tanto, cualquier cambio que realices en una, se ve inmediatamente reflejado en las demás ... porque todas son en realidad la misma.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!. ,me quedo super claro.